# Can I delete any of these items from library?

Tags: mac, disk-space, big-sur, library

[image: library space]

I erased my hard drive and installed Big Sur from a bootable hard drive. I don’t know why it takes up almost 15GB on an erased hard drive.

Update: I just noticed on Disk Utility that 14.9GB is used for snapshot name: com.apple.is.update-{a long list of numbers}.
Any ideas if there is a safe way to delete a snapshot? I don’t know if these is stored with the VM.[image][image]

Comment: Just for clarification, the system and the drive your working with has this library folder with 15GB or is that on an external drive that **was** being used as a boot drive but is not anymore?

Comment: The system and drive has the 15GB. When I used the command diskutil list, It shows up under APFS container Scheme, disk1s5 and under disk1s5s1.

Comment: The **macOS Big Sur** installer is around 12.21 GB downloaded and a clean install from it is around 18 GB, so there is nothing abnormal here, and you definitely should not be deleting things from from the system's Library folder!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, apparently this is normal. Saw a discussion stating that the 15GB volume secured files from malware according to this discussion on an apple thread. So I guess it has to stay. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252032330

Comment: Just as a tip: Next time, try to find the solution to your problem first by googling yourself. Questions that can be answered more or less by googling are not very much liked by the community since they have to do work you could have done yourself...

Comment: I have been for two days googling.

Answer (score 0):

None of those should be deleted. I would use other places to trim space if needed.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206996 ( How to free up storage space on your Mac )